# Добрый день. Хочу загрузить библиотеки спринга через мавен. Но в ПОМ файле мавен выдаёт красные ошибки

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, maven, зависимости

Хочу загрузить библиотеки спринга через мавен. Но в ПОМ файле мавен выдаёт красные ошибки
При наведении, идеа выдает : Dependency 'org.springframework:spring-context:6.1.2' not found

Зависимости брал из Maven repository

JDK 17

IDEA 2020.1.1

Maven 3.9.4[image: pom.xml]

Comment: Если мышку на красное навести, что пишет? Обычно там указана ошибка.

Comment: Dependency 'org.springframework:spring-context (номер версии) not found

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: На скриншоте у вас показана зависимость `spring-core` с версией `5.1.4.RELEASE` (январь 2019), а в тексте -- `spring-context` версии `6.1.2` (декабрь 2023).  Так какие у вас реально зависимости указаны в `pom.xml`?

Comment: С любой версией возникает ошибка. и с версией 5.1.4.RELEASE, и с версией 6.1.2.

Comment: Пробуйте  `mvn clean` + `mvn compile`, затем почистить кеш и перезапустить идею (invalidate cache & restart) .  Также следует отредактировать вопрос и привести `pom.xml` (текст) и текст сообщения об ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать небольшие изменения в pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

также укажите компилятор maven вместо `1.7` поменяйте на `17`

Если выше указанное не помогло попробуйте сделать `mvn clean` + `mvn package`

Если это также не поможет убедитесь что вы правильно сконфигурировали проект

У idea иногда бывают баги может помочь перезапуск

Comment: maven clean+package помогло
Спасибо